# Seeking (reasonably priced) eCos development board

Tags: embedded, ecos

I heard about [eCos](http://ecos.sourceware.org/) and it looks like it would be fun to play about with as a hobby project.

Can anyone recommend a reasonably priced development board.If it doesn't add too much to the cost, I'd like to have a few buttons to press (and detect the press programatically) and an LCD for some debug output. Ethernet would be nice (hmm, maybe also wifi USB and BlueTooth, if they don't add too much to the cost).

Any suggestions?   (I usually develop for ARM 7 or 9, but do need the same for playing around?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [supported hardware page](http://ecos.sourceware.org/hardware.html), second column.  Those are all the out-of-the-box supported boards.

Buttons and LCDs or LEDs are commonly available.  Ethernet less so.  Wireless USB and Bluetooth I rarely see, though some have support for ZigBee.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that page. What I am looking for is where to buy a board, preferably one with buttons, LCD, Ethernet, wtc ...

Comment: Oh, okay.  Several of them are available from Digi-Key: www.digikey.com.  Digi-Key has a *lot* of parts and hardware available.